# Bounds on the components of a vector in a F.D.V.S.

Tags: normed-spaces, vector-analysis

If $v_1,...,v_k$ is a basis of $V$ (an inner product vector space) and $v\in V$, we can write $$v=a_1v_1+...+a_kv_k$$ I was wondering if $\lvert a_i \rvert$ is bounded by some function depending on $\lvert \lvert v \rvert \rvert$ and $\lvert \lvert v_1 \rvert \rvert ,...,\lvert \lvert v_k \rvert \rvert \ \ \ (i=1,...,k)$ such as $$\frac{\lvert \lvert v \rvert \rvert}{\lvert \lvert v_1 \rvert \rvert +...+\lvert \lvert v_k \rvert \rvert}$$ All I have is that if $v_1,...,v_k$ is orthonormal then $$\lvert a_i \rvert \le \lvert \lvert v \rvert \rvert$$

Comment: Let $V=\begin{bmatrix} v_1 & \cdots & v_k \end{bmatrix}$. It is not hard to show that $V^*V$ is positive definite and if $v=\sum_i \alpha_i v_i$ then $V \alpha = v$ and so $\alpha = (V^*V)^{-1} V^* v$. Hence $\|\alpha\| \le \| (V^*V)^{-1} V^* \| \|v\|$.

Comment: Can You do a Proof without using matrices? Because V need not be the set of kx1 matrices, and the fact that You assumed it is confuses me

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $v = \sum_k \alpha_k v_k$ then
$\langle v_i, v \rangle = \sum_k \alpha_k \langle v_i, v_k \rangle$.

Let $[A]_{ij} = \langle v_i, v_j \rangle$, it is straightforward to show that $A$ is positive definite and so invertible. Let $[b]_i = \langle v_i, v \rangle$, and we see that $A \alpha = b$ and so
$\alpha = A^{-1} b$.

Using Cauchy Schwartz, note that $\|b\| \le \sqrt{\|v_1\|^2+\cdots \|v_k\|^2} \|v\|$, and so
$\| \alpha \| \le \|A^{-1}\| \sqrt{\|v_1\|^2+\cdots \|v_k\|^2} \|v\|$.

Comment: A is a linear map or a matrix? in that case what is $\rvert \vert A^-1\lvert \lvert$. I would like to accept your answer but i need to understand your notation.

Comment: Yes, $A$ is a matrix whose $i,j$ element is given above.